# knex : How can I create an object from results?

Tags: mysql, node.js, knex.js

Mysql version : 5.7.23
knex.js version : 0.15.2

Now I have 3 tables to join each other

```
table: projects
  - id (pk)
  - project_name
  - project_detail

table: user_projects
  - project_id (pk, fk from projects)
  - user_id (pk, fk from users)
  - success_percent

table: project_todos
  - id (pk)
  - project_id (fk from projects)
  - user_id (fk from users)
  - todo_detail
  - status
  - will_finish_date
```

I want to join 3 tables and then result is

```
{
      project_name: "lorem ipsum",
      project_detail: "",
      success_percent: 50,
      todos: [
         {
           id: 1,
           todo_detail: "sleep",
           status: 0,
           will_finish_date: 2018-11-11
         },
         {
           id: 2,
           todo_detail: "eat",
           status: 1,
           will_finish_date: 2018-11-11
         }
      ]
   }
```

My code is

```
getUserProject: (userId, select = '*', groupBy) => {
return knex('user_project')
  .join('projects', 'projects.id', 'user_project.project_id')
  .join('project_roles', 'project_roles.id', 'user_project.role_id')
  .join('project_todos', {
    'projects.id': 'project_todos.project_id',
    'project_todos.user_id': userId
  })
  .where('user_project.user_id', userId)
  .groupBy(groupBy)
  .select(select)
  }
```

It's error

UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''project_todos.todo_detail','project_todos.status','project_todos.will_finish_da' at line 1

Thanks for helping in advance